# Owlcarousel (1.3.3): Adding Item without jumping back

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

I am creating a site where content is dynamically loaded using Ajax into OwlCarousel items, which are created as needed using the addItem() method.

As can be seen on the demo at http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/manipulations.html, when addItem is called, the carousel always jumps back to the first item (i.e. to the extreme left, or the first 'page'). I would like it to scroll automatically to the newly created item (i.e. to the extreme right or last 'page', to show the newly-created item). Is there some way to modify the code to make this happen? It seems that as soon as addItem() is called, the carousel jumps.

Comment: Have you considered asking the OwlCarousel developers? https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel/issues

Comment: Have you any minimal code that you could share here?

Comment: yes, I emailed the developer already, thanks.
Here is the call from my own javascript, which creates the new item, loads the content, and moves to the new item.
What happens is that it will jump all the way back and only then scroll to the new item. ('panels' is the owlCarousel object)

function openPanel(url) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#panels').data('owlCarousel').addItem(data, panelCount);
       panelCount++;
    $('#panels').data('owlCarousel').goTo(panelCount);
      }
    });
    
    return false;
}

Comment: Well done - you should add this as an answer.